# Using two BLoCs in same page and passing first BLoC's state in second BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, state, bloc, chopper

I have been learning about Bloc Pattern in Flutter for a few days.

1. I have a page where I need to generate OTP and validate it.
2. There are two APIs(generateOtp, validateOtp) two implement this functionality.
3. In the generateOtp API response, I need to save one key i.e uniqueIdentifier.
4. Then I need to pass the above uniqueIdentifier and Otp value(User entered) to the validateOtp API.
5. I have created two separate BLoCs... generateOtpBloc, validateOtpBloc.
6. Using MultiBLoC Provider I am using these two BLoCs.

```
                            Navigator.of(context).push(
                              MaterialPageRoute<LandingPage>(
                                builder: (_) => MultiBlocProvider(
                                  providers: [
                                    BlocProvider<GenerateOtpBloc>(
                                      create: (context) => GenerateOtpBloc(GenerateOtpInitial())
                                    ),
                                    BlocProvider<ValidateOtpBloc>(
                                      create: (context) => ValidateOtpBloc(ValidateOtpInitial())
                                    )
                                  ],
                                  child: OtpPage(),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
```

7. I am able to invoke APIs and get the API responses in my UI page.

But how to save the uniqueIdentifier value which I get in the generateOtp and how to pass this uniqueIdentifier in the second API?

I thought of using setState() to set the state of uniqueIdentifier. But I'm receiving an error.

```
          child: BlocBuilder<GenerateOtpBloc, GenerateOtpState>(
            builder: (context, state) {
              if (state is GenerateOtpLoading) {
                print("**********GenerateOtpLoading*************");

                return buildLoading();
              } else if (state is GenerateOtpLoaded) {
                print("**********GenerateOtpLoaded*************");

                ***//But Im getting error here.***
                ***setState(() {
                  uniqueIdentifier: state.uniqueIdentifier
                });***

                return buildGenerateOtpWidget(context, state.generateOtpRes);
              } else {
                print("**********Else*************");
                print(state);
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Both generateOtp and validateOtp requests and responses are completely different... that is why I used two different BLoCs.

Suggest to me the best way to handle this?

Comment: you can listen to a bloc form another bloc please take a look at this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ricBLKHeubM

Answer (score 1):

Why you try to use two `bloc`s for handle it? you can use two `event`s in one `bloc`. This is my code in the OTP login project similar to your project:

```
class LoginBloc extends Bloc<LoginEvent, LoginState> {
  FirstApiClass _firstApi;
  SecondApiClass _secondApi;

  LoginBloc() : super(Loading()) {
    _firstApi = FirstApiClass();
    _secondApi = SecondApiClass();
  }

  @override
  Stream<LoginState> mapEventToState(
    LoginEvent event,
  ) async* {
      if (event is GenerateOtp) {
        // Use FirstApiClass
      } else if (event is ValidateOtpBloc) {
        // Use SecondApiClass
      }
  }
}
```

However, you can also use one Api class for this situation!
I hope it's useful for you.